# Embedding PDF in an MVC view from binary data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, embed, binary-data

My issue is I'm currently receiving from a web service response a string that is the binary data of a PDF file. I need to display this PDF file embedded in an MVC view. I'm using C#.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm looking to embed the PDF in an <iframe> or <object> since there's going to be other content in the page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: the concept is pretty much the same, you just need to create a page that contains an iframe and make that iframe point to the view that renders the pdf. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just return it using [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). Something like this:

```
public ActionResult ShowPDF()
{
  byte[] pdf = myService.GetPDF();
  return File(pdf, "application/pdf");      
}
```

**UPDATE**

Create a page containing a `iframe` element and set the `src` attribute to point to your view that renders the PDF file. Here is an example taken from [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe-pdf.html)

```
<iframe src="ShowPDF" width="100%" style="height:20em">

 [Your browser does <em>not</em> support <code>iframe</code>,
 or has been configured not to display inline frames.
 You can access <a href="ShowPDF">the document</a>
 via a link though.]

</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I've found another way to do this is to set a ViewData entry to:

ViewData["PDF_src"] = "data:application/pdf;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(PDF_src);

and to have the iframe src attribute set to this value.

Comment: Yep, same thing. Our solutions, in essence, are the same. I'd stay away from ViewData though.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has added the embed tag which allows a variety of rich content to be embedded into the page as follows:`<embed src="your file path here" type="application/pdf" />`